# Is it safe to archive Dictionary with String as a key?

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, nsarchiving

According to Apple docs, hash value of string may not be stable across different invocations of app:

> The hash value is not guaranteed to be stable across different invocations of the same program. Do not persist the hash value across program runs.
>   [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structp/String/s:vSS9hashValueSi)

Is it safe to archive (by NSArchive) dictionary of the following type `[String: AnyObject]`?
If so, how Dictionary prevents from instability? Does it archive dictionary as array of tuples, like `[(key, value)]`?

Comment: I don't know the answer but thank you for sharing your question, very useful.

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: Are you asking about the format of an NSKeyedArchiver archive?  The warning simply means that you shouldn't store the hashes outside of the dictionary and expect the unarchived dict to have the same hashes when unarchived.  It doesn't mean you can't archive a dictionary.

Comment: `[String: AnyObject]` is mapped to  `NSDictionary` and that conforms to `NSCoding` and thus supports archiving. *How* that is done is an implementation detail.